# Expected value of the function of log-normally distributed variables

Tags: probability

I would like to find out what is the expected value of this random variable $\frac{x_1e^{x_1}}{\sum _{i=1}^{k}e^{x_i}}$ if $x_i$ are independent random variables, all distributed normally with mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$.

I think it is equal to something like this:

$$E \Biggl ( \frac{x_1e^{x_1}}{\sum _{i=1}^{k}e^{x_i}} \Biggr ) =  \frac{1}{(\sqrt {2 \pi} \sigma)^k}  \int \int \dots \int \frac{x_1e^{x_1}}{\sum _{i=1}^{k}e^{x_i}} e^{- \sum _{i=1}^{k}  \frac {(x_i - \mu)^2}{2 \sigma^2}} \,dx_1 \,dx_2 \dots \,dx_k$$

but I have no idea how to move on.

Comment: Are you looking for an exact value or an approximation?

Comment: Ideally an exact value.